# Get an instance of generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have 2 Customer classes BusinessCustomer and NormalCustomer having individual properties and a Validate Method. From the implement class, based on some condition I might create Customer1 or Customer2. 
How can I create an instance of either BusinessCustomer  or NormalCustomer based on T in Customer class so that I can call the validate method common to both the classes.

```
    public class Customer<T> where T : class
    {
        public T CustomerType;
        bool isValid;

        public Customer() //constructor
        {
            //for customer1, i want a new instance of BusinessCustomer 
            //for customer2, i want a new instance of NormalCustomer 
        }

        public bool Validate()
        {
            isValid = CustomerType.Validate();
        }
    }


public class BusinessCustomer
{
    public string CustomerHobby { get; set; }
    public bool Validate()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class NormalCustomer
{
    public string CustomerEducation { get; set; }
    public bool Validate()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Implement
{
    public void ImplementCustomer()
    {
        var customer1 = new Customer<BusinessCustomer>();
        customer1.CustomerType = new BusinessCustomer {CustomerHobby="Singing"};
        customer1.Validate();

        var customer2 = new Customer<NormalCustomer>();
        customer2.CustomerType = new NormalCustomer { CustomerEducation = "High School" };
        customer2.Validate();

    }
}
```

Comment: Question was closed before I could write an answer, but basically you'd want `BusinessCustomer` and `NormalCustomer` to both implement an interface, `ICustomer`, which has a `Validate` method.  You'd then change `Customer<T> where T : class` to `Customer<T> where T : ICustomer`.  At this point, you can call `Validate` on `CustomerType`, since the compiler can now know the method exists.

Comment: @Mike, am I missing something?  It appeared to me the OP wanted clarification on how to accomplish what he commented on in his constructor, namely: "`//for customer1, i want a new instance of BusinessCustomer`"  Clearly the answer to that is found in the answer referenced via the duplicate.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I had trouble understanding the question, but from what I can tell, they want to be able to call `Validate()` on `CustomerType`, which would require `T` to share a common interface.  But yes, it seems they *also* want to create default instances of that type within the constructor, even though they're doing this in `ImplementCustomer` already.  I'd rather the question have been closed as *Unclear*.

Comment: @Mike, I see your point, and have re-opened the question.  Feel free to have at it. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll - Thanks!  Probably spent more time on that than it was worth.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Adding the interface helped it. Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is with the following line:

```
isValid = CustomerType.Validate();
```

Since `CustomerType` is of type `T`, which can be *any class*, the compiler can't guarantee there's a `Validate()` method to be called.  You'll need to fix this by creating a common interface.  Let's call this `ICustomer`:

```
interface ICustomer
{
   bool Validate();
}
```

Now, both `BusinessCustomer` and `NormalCustomer` will need to implement said interface:

```
public class BusinessCustomer : ICustomer
{
   // Same code
}

public class NormalCustomer : ICustomer
{
   // Same code
}
```

Next, you'll have to change:

```
public class Customer<T> where T : class
```

To:

```
public class Customer<T> where T : ICustomer
```

Now, you'll only be able to create `Customer<T>` instances where `T` *implements* `ICustomer`, which will allow you to call the `Validate` method of `CustomerType`.

Next, if you wanted to *new up* a `T` in your constructor, you can do so like:

```
public Customer()
{
   CustomerType = new T();
}
```

But wait.  What if `T` doesn't have a default public constructor, or is abstract?  We'll also need to add this *constraint* to our generic type:

```
public class Customer<T> where T : class, new()
```

Now, `new T();` works and you can only create instances of `Customer<T>` where `T` has a default constructor.  You'll no longer have to set `customer1.CustomerType` if you don't want to.

Another quick note.  Your method:

```
public bool Validate()
{
   isValid = CustomerType.Validate();
}
```

Either needs to *return* a bool (such as `isValid`), or the signature needs to be `void Validate()`.  Right now, you'll get a compiler error because not all code paths return a value.

Hope this helps!